# what is __return_false in filters

Tags: filters, admin-bar

I was thinking of removing/hiding admin-bar from my wordpress (3.1.1) installation.

I visited following link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/show_admin_bar

I was surprised to see only a single line to remove/hide admin-bar

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

My question is what is **__return_false** means? why __ and _?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

#### WordPress contains built in functions for quickly returning values.

They are intended to be used as a quick built in function that returns a common value to a filter hook such as true, false, or an empty array.

- `__return_false`  — Returns the Boolean value of `false`.
- `__return_true`  — Returns the Boolean value of `true`.
- `__return_empty_array`  — Returns an empty PHP `array`.
- `__return_zero`  — Returns the integer `0`.
- `__return_null`  —  Returns `NULL`.
- `__return_empty_string` — Returns `''`.

Comment: I cannot see a meaningful reason for these constants.

Comment: They aren't constant, they're actual functions. This saves you from having to code something like
`function justToReturnFalse() {
    return false;
}`

Comment: they are mostly useful in writing short anonymous function attached to filters, like `\add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_enabled_new_order, '__return_false' );`